# Integration tests fails on the Magic Bytes check on an upload-image endpoint

Tags: c#, .net, file-upload, integration-testing

We have a simple rest API. One of its endpoints is to include magicBytes validation, which currently looks like this

```cs
private static bool HaveValidMagicBytes(IFormFile file)
{
    if (file == null || !MagicBytes.TryGetValue(file.ContentType, out byte[] magicBytes))
    {
        return false;
    }

    using (Stream stream = file.OpenReadStream())
    {
        var fileMagicBytes = new byte[magicBytes.Length];
        stream.Read(fileMagicBytes, 0, magicBytes.Length);
        bool haveValidMagicBytes = magicBytes.SequenceEqual(fileMagicBytes);
        return haveValidMagicBytes;
    }
}
```

We have existing integration tests for this, but I can't seem to get them to work with the above piece of code.

I currently prep the 'mocked image for the api endpoint':

```cs
private MultipartFormDataContent SetupFileImageTests(string fileName)
{
    var realFile = File.OpenRead(ImageHelper.GetImagePath()); //points to a local, valid file: TestData/test_image.PNG

    var mockedFile = new Mock<IFormFile>();
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    var writer = new StreamWriter(ms);
    writer.Write(realFile);
    writer.Flush();
    ms.Position = 0;
    mockedFile.Setup(c => c.OpenReadStream()).Returns(ms);
    mockedFile.Setup(f => f.FileName).Returns(fileName).Verifiable();
    mockedFile.Setup(_ => _.CopyToAsync(It.IsAny<Stream>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
        .Returns((Stream stream, CancellationToken token) => ms.CopyToAsync(stream))
        .Verifiable();

    writer.Write(FileContent);
    writer.Flush();
    ms.Position = 0;

    mockedFile.Setup(f => f.OpenReadStream()).Returns(ms);
    mockedFile.Setup(f => f.Length).Returns(ms.Length);
    mockedFile.Setup(f => f.FileName).Returns(fileName);

    var fileContent = new StreamContent(mockedFile.Object.OpenReadStream())
    {
        Headers =
        {
            ContentLength = mockedFile.Object.Length,
            ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg")
        }
    };

    return new MultipartFormDataContent
    {
        {fileContent, "file", fileName}
    };
}
```

I've tried adding an actual, real image, so that the check should succeed in theory, but it's still not. I'm not quite sure how to proceed.
`haveValidMagicBytes` is still false and thus causing the whole thing to crash.

Comment: 1) Please provide a [mre] 2) check that number returned by `stream.Read(fileMagicBytes, 0, magicBytes.Length);` is actually equal to `magicBytes.Length`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you use

```
new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg")
```

but your file is

```
TestData/test_image.PNG
```

So you should either use `image/png` or change your test to ignore the content type, and instead compare the magic bytes with a list of known file formats you accept.

Comment: I was able to solve it by removing all of the mocked stuff, plus just passing the file. See https://gunnarpeipman.com/aspnet-core-integration-test-file-upload/ 
And I also had to change the MediaTypeHeaderValue indeed!